# Infinite loop wait 2 second, make server call jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am making a simple game with jquery and i want to make a call to asp.net web service which i  know how to do, but the server call need to continue to run until i get a specific response from the server.

I will wait like 3 seconds with each loop cycle

```
function servercall() {
            while (true) {
                // code for clone and insert  ...
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Server.asmx/HelloWorld",
                    data: "{'name': '" + $('#name').val() + "', 'time': '2pm'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        AjaxSucceeded(msg);
                    },
                    error: AjaxFailed
                });
                setTimeout("nothing", 2000);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make an infinite loop run for 2 seconds? :) I wish I knew how to do that!

Comment: I think he wants a loop with a delay in between each iteration.  No hill for a climber, using recursion.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use recursion with `setTimeout`.  And be sure start the timer when you receive a response, so that you account for network delays (you don't want a bunch of requests going at the same time)...

```
function servercall() { 
  $.ajax({ 
    complete: function(xhr) { 
      var msg = xhr.responseText;
      if(xhr.statusCode == 200)
        AjaxSucceeded(msg); 
      else
        AjaxFailed(msg);

      setTimeout(servercall, 2000); //recursion magic
    }
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the JavaScript [setTimeout() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You could try either:

```
function serverCall() {
    // ajax code

    setTimeout("serverCall()", 2000);
}
```

or:

```
function ajaxSucceeded(msg) {
    if (isTheAnswerYouAreLookingFor) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        setTimeout("serverCall()", 2000);
    }
}
```

Here is an article on setTimeout and setInterval that may help you further:
http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Answer (score -1):

Set interval is more helpful :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

setInterval("servercall()", 2000);

function servercall() {

                // code for clone and insert  ...
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Server.asmx/HelloWorld",
                    data: "{'name': '" + $('#name').val() + "', 'time': '2pm'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        AjaxSucceeded(msg);
                    },
                    error: AjaxFailed
                });

            }

        }

</script>
```

Comment: What if they have slow internet and it takes a second for each response?

Comment: Its something one has to take into consideration if one has decided todo an infinite loop AJAX calls. He asked for 2 seconds i gave him two seconds.

Comment: All I am saying is that this could potentially have multiple requests going at once, which is never desired.

Comment: The only thing that he can do is either drop the plan or increase the wait time to 10 seconds or more.